# Matrix equation solving

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I am new to Mathematica and I try to apply the solution given to this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328911/compute-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-with-partially-known-values).
So I have:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}50 & 3 & 10 & 2\\\ 3 & 60 & 7 & 1\\\ 10 & 7 & 55 & 4\\\ 2 & 1 & 4 & 45 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} & 0\\\ b_{12} & b_{22} & 0 & 0\\\ b_{13} & 0 & b_{33} & b_{34}\\\ 0 & 0 & b_{34} & b_{44} \end{pmatrix}$$

The idea is to invert $B$, and then solve the equations element-wise between the elements of $A$ and the elements of $B^{-1}$.
The invert of $B$ is:
[image: B inverted]

Code:

```
A = {{50, 3, 10, 2}, {3, 60, 7, 1}, {10, 7, 55, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 45}}
B = {{b11, b12, b13, 0}, {b12, b22, 0, 0}, {b13, 0, b33, b34}, {0, 0, 
      b34, b44}}
B2 = Inverse[B]
```

Now, I would like to solve the equations $B2_{i, j} = A_{i, j}$ to figure out the 7 parameters: $b_{11}, b_{12}, b_{13}, b_{22}, b_{33}, b_{34}, b_{44}$. In other words, I want to get $B^{-1}_{i, j}=A_{i, j}$ if $B_{ij} \neq 0$.

How can I solve this system of equations with Mathematica?

Bonus: Knowing that the actualy matrix have a shape of 16 per 16, and that there are 64 parameters $b_{i, j}$, is this problem solvable with Mathematica or should I try something else?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Please do follow this advice: Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always show your due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your **code** and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). Links and images are not a substitute for including code and information in your question itself. Please [edit] your question,so you can inspire somebody to volunteer their time on your problem

Comment: @rhermans I apologize for the lack of code... but inputting the 2 matrix and computing the inverse is done in 3 lines. (I've added them above for copy/paste purposes). I am completely stuck with the equation solving part... My best guess would be to copy/paste each equation in the Solve function... which would be ok for this 4 by 4 matrix but far too long for the full-scale matrix with 64 parameters.

Comment: If you want $B^{-1}$ to be the same as $A$, it is not possible. If it was then `A.B - IdentityMatrix[4]` would be all zeroes, but `Minimize[Norm[A.B - IdentityMatrix[4], "Frobenius"], Variables[B]]` returns a non-zero error.

Comment: @Coolwater, that is my bad, I should have placed a bit more information in my post. I do want $B^{-1}$ to be the same as $A$ for elements $(i, j)$ where $B_{i, j} is not 0$. Thus the 2 matrix are different.

Comment: To chime in with @Coolwater: if $A=B^{-1}$, then also $B=A^{-1}$. Calculating $A^{-1}$ with `Inverse[A]` we find no zeros in the result, and so there is no solution. Nonetheless you can read off those elements of $B$ that are nonzero directly from `Inverse[A]`.

Comment: @Roman Yes and as I explained, you didn't get the problem. Of course there is no solution for what you propose. I don't want to find the complete matrix A when I inverse B, I only want to find the element $A_{i, j}$ for (i, j) where $B_{i, j}$ is not equal to 0. I don't care about the other elements in A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we need to do is filter the equations in $B^{-1}=A$ to only positions where original elements of $B$ are non-zero. I'll use pattern-matching to create new matrices $A$ and $B^{-1}$ that change all elements to $0$ that are zero in B.

Using a symmetric definition of $B$ (sorry about the subscript formatting)

```
B = {{Subscript[b, 11], Subscript[b, 12], Subscript[b, 13], 
    0}, {Subscript[b, 12], Subscript[b, 22], 0, 0}, {Subscript[b, 13],
     0, Subscript[b, 33], Subscript[b, 34]}, {0, 0, Subscript[b, 34], 
    Subscript[b, 44]}};
Binv = Inverse[B];
Solve[Table[
   If[MatchQ[B[[i, j]], Subscript[b, i_]], Binv[[i, j]], 0], {i, 
    4}, {j, 4}] == 
  Table[If[MatchQ[B[[i, j]], Subscript[b, i_]], A[[i, j]], 0], {i, 
    4}, {j, 4}]]
```

The solution is

$$B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}\frac{27497}{1321025} & -\frac{1}{997} & -\frac{1}{265} & 0 \\-\frac{1}{997} & \frac{50}{2991} & 0 & 0 \\-\frac{1}{265} & 0 & \frac{136093}{7167985} & -\frac{4}{2459} \\0 & 0 & -\frac{4}{2459} & \frac{55}{2459} \\\end{array}\right)$$

And

$$B^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}50 & 3 & 10 & \frac{8}{11} \\3 & 60 & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{12}{275} \\10 & \frac{3}{5} & 55 & 4 \\\frac{8}{11} & \frac{12}{275} & 4 & 45 \\\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: As I have the answer on the other question, I guess this is correct :) However, could you explain a bit your script (what does it do?) and what are the Subscript? My main problem is that I don't know Mathematica at all and I need to adapt this code for a larger matrix.

Comment: Especially the Subscript[b, i_]] feels weird. I understand that you create 2 tables (matrix) for A and B where you put 0 if Bi,j is 0, but why is there an underscore and not j in this subscript? I guess in the table brackets, the {i, 4}, {j, 4} are here to specify the iteration?

Comment: And if i_ is for the iteration on i, where is the iteration on j?

Answer (score 3):

The user provided matrices:

```
mA = {{50, 3, 10, 2}, {3, 60, 7, 1}, {10, 7, 55, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 45}}
mB = {{b11, b12, b13, 0}, {b12, b22, 0, 0}, {b13, 0, b33, b34}, {0, 0,b34, b44}}
```

Parameterize `mA` where `mB` has a zero.  (See the docs for `Indexed`.)

```
mAnext = MapIndexed[
  If[TrueQ[0 == Extract[mB, #2]], Indexed[a, #2], #1] &, mA, {2}]
```

Extract the parameters from the two matrices and create a single parameter vector.

```
prmsA = Cases[Catenate@mAnext, _Indexed]
prmsB = DeleteCases[Catenate[mB], 0]
prms = Join[prmsA, prmsB]
```

Impose that the inverse of `mB` equals `mAnext` and solve:

```
mI = IdentityMatrix[4]
Solve[mI == mB.mAnext, prms]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, as I am a beginner in Mathematica, could you comment your code please?